# Is this brute force?

Tags: java

I just solved the Pythagorean Triples common problem, the version of every both  sides of the triangle and the hypotenuse are all minor than 500... the problem says that we should find all the values of side1 and side2 that make a a square triangle.

my questions are:

1. is this brute force?
2. does brute force mean that the results could be found in a prior iteration and then every solution could be a repetition?

i leave my code (note: this code finds multiple repeated soultions, so I don't know if it's a bad code or the actual definition  of this concept)

```
public class TriplePitagoras {
    public static void main (String args[]){

        for ( int side1 = 1 ; side1 <= 500 ; side1++ ){
            for ( int side2 = side1 ; side2 <= 500 ; side2++ )
                for ( int hypotenuse = side2 ; hypotenuse <= 500 ; hypotenuse++ ){
                    if ( (int) Math.pow(hypotenuse, 2) == (int) ( Math.pow(side1,2) + Math.pow(side2,2) ) )
                        System.out.printf("hypotenuse = %d, side1 = %d, side2 = %d \n", hypotenuse, side1, side2);
                }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26876971/6178459

Comment: What do you mean, duplicates? Each triple it generates is unique.  While there are duplicate hypotenuses, each of the duplicate hypotenuses are combined with different side1 and side2.  There aren't duplicates even for switched sides.  For example, side1=3, side2=4, hypotenuse=5 is represented just once and not again as side1=4, side2=3, hypotenuse=5.  This is guaranteed by your code because for each side1 it tests, it always tests values of side2 that are equal or higher than side1, and pythagorean triples with equal side1 and side2 simply do not exist.

Comment: Thanks m8! now i've got a better picture of this subject

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a [brute force approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search), although the worst case would be if you start all loops from 1.

Brute forcing your way up to a solution just means you start generating all possible combinations and then exclude those that don't match your particular criteria, in this case everything for which a^2 + b^2 != c^2.

You are not looking at the properties of the numbers to try to figure out some formula to derive one from the others, or try to reduce the numbers of tests that you have to run, etc, you use [muscles instead of brains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103050/what-exactly-is-the-brute-force-algorithm) to get to a result, that's why it's called brute force.

Your PC might run all combinations very fast, but for some cases you need [a more elegant approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples).

Comment: Thanks @Bogdan I also wanted to know if duplicated solutions are a problem or if that's normal in brute force approaches.